# Mysql join for thread and its replies

Tags: php, mysql, forum

Ok, I am willing to create a simple forum for my website. So, let's begin.

I guess thread table is going to be smth like this:

```
t_id, thread_name, who_created, when_created
```

And replies table is going to be smth like this:

```
r_id, t_id, who_wrote, what_wrote, when_wrote
```

And when somebody wants to view thread with replies, he clicks button which moves him to `index.php?t_id=1` or smth like that. `t_id` means threads' table value `t_id`. What join query should I write for showing topic and its replies?

```
mysql_query('SELECT *
             FROM threads AS t
             INNER JOIN replies AS r
             ON t.t_id = r.t_id
             WHERE t.t_id = '.mysql_escape_strings($_GET['t_id']));
```

Is it right? Then how should I pull out all that data? With mysql_fetch_array? Then how? Any suggestions? Maybe better write 2 queries instead of JOIN? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a join in this case as it does not give any advantage and instead it will slow down the queries. Rather do two separate queries:

```
mysql_query('SELECT *
         FROM threads AS t
         WHERE t.t_id = '.mysql_escape_strings($_GET['t_id']));
```

And:

```
mysql_query('SELECT *
         FROM replies AS r
         WHERE r.t_id = '.mysql_escape_strings($_GET['t_id']));
```

This will be much faster.

Comment: The join gives you exactly the same information as the two-query approach, but because it duplicates the thread table's columns for each reply, it will produce a larger amount of (redundant) data. +1.